# Doctrine CASE WHEN

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4, doctrine-query

I am building an application with Symfony 3.4 and Dcotrine.

The following SQL-Statement is working fine within my database:

```
SELECT * FROM `report` 
INNER JOIN report_template ON `template_id` = report_template.id INNER JOIN game ON game.id = `game_id`
WHERE (game.refereeAId='Hoehl Luca,SpVgg Altenerding' or game.refereeBId='Hoehl Luca,SpVgg Altenerding')
AND report.creator_id LIKE (CASE WHEN report.template_id=1 THEN 136 ELSE '%' END)
```

Now I want this statement in Doctrine:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('r');
$query->innerjoin('r.game', 'g')
->innerjoin('r.template', 't')
->innerjoin('r.creator', 'c');

$query->andwhere('g.refereeAId = :refereeName or g.refereeBId = :refereeName')
      ->andWhere('r.approved = :approved')
      ->andWhere('c.id LIKE CASE WHEN r.template = :template THEN :user ELSE \'%\' END')
      ->setParameter('approved', true)
      ->setParameter('refereeName', $refereeID)
      ->setParameter('template', $templates[1])
      ->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
```

I get the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\GeneralCaseExpression::$type
```

I have tried so many combinations in the LIKE CASE block, nothing worked. Does anybody knows how to add this block in Doctrine?

Best regards
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `WHEN` close, is located in `Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\WhenClause`.

`WhenClause ::= "WHEN" ConditionalExpression "THEN" ScalarExpression`.